# Manually instantiating ReactNative components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It seems like that in ReactNative that you can do something like `new SomeComponent(props)` and `return someComponent.render()`. I'm guessing this is basically what the JSX does when you directly declare `<SomeComponent someProp="etc"/>`? If that's the case, is there any potential downsides to manually manipulating the components rather than using JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like that in ReactNative that you can do something like new
>   SomeComponent(props) and return someComponent.render()

Not really. If you manually instantiate a component class, among other things lifecycle methods (`componentWillMount()`, `componentDidMount(`)) won't work.

> I'm guessing this is basically what the JSX does when you directly
>   declare

Have a look at what babel compiles to, but basically JSX compiles down to plain js:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>;
  }
}
```

translates to:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}
```

> If that's the case, is there any potential downsides to manually
>   manipulating the components rather than using JSX

You could use `React.createElement` and completely avoid JSX, but in my experience this is harder and more verbose. Manually instantiating components though like you initially suggested defeats the purpose of using React :)

Some good links which go in more detail:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html